# MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$expr' on using $divide and $expr in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

New to Mongodb.

What I'm attemping to do is create a formula that returns documents if the rent value is $gte to 1% of the price value.

Right now I have both price and rent values stored in the database but not the 1% value.

I tried the code below but I get this error 
`MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$expr'`

Here's my code

```
agg = [
        {
            "$set": {
                "onePercent": { '$divide': ["$price", 100] }
            }
        },
        {
            "$expr": {
                $gte: ["$rent", "$onePercent",]
            }
        },
    ]
    let res = client.db('myDb').collection('myCollection').aggregate(agg)
```

How can I make a query that would return the documents I'm attempting to select?

Comment: Is it working or still having issues ?

Comment: got it workin!  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to compare two fields inside a document. Where `$expr` is an operator but not an aggregation stage. So operators needs to be used inside stages, can't stand on their own in an aggregation pipeline `[{ stage1: {operators...} }, { stage2: {operators...} },...,{ stageN: {operators...} }]`.

MongoDB's aggregation stage [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) helps to filter documents based on condition.

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $gte: ["$rent", "$onePercent"] } } } // your filter condition { $gte: ["$rent", "$onePercent"] }
```